# Python staticmaps failing to retrive image, ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python

Im trying to get a satellite image with specific center coordinates and zoom via staticmaps

```py
import staticmaps
import s2sphere 

context = staticmaps.Context()

context.set_tile_provider(staticmaps.tile_provider_ArcGISWorldImagery)

context.set_zoom(1)
context.set_center(s2sphere.LatLng(54.163849, -4.487915))

image = context.render_pillow(500, 500)
image.show()
```

But i get the following error:

```
File "/home/user/Projects/a/b/c/d/api.py", line 29, 
    image = context.render_pillow(500, 500)
  File "/home/user/Projects/a/b/lib/python3.10/site-packages/staticmaps/context.py", line 147, in render_pillow
    trans = Transformer(width, height, zoom, center, self._tile_provider.tile_size())
  File "/home/user/Projects/a/b/lib/python3.10/site-packages/staticmaps/transformer.py", line 22, in __init__
    self._tile_center_x, self._tile_center_y = self.ll2t(center)
  File "/home/user/Projects/a/b/lib/python3.10/site-packages/staticmaps/transformer.py", line 182, in ll2t
    x, y = self.mercator(latlng)
  File "/home/user/Projects/a/b/lib/python3.10/site-packages/staticmaps/transformer.py", line 156, in mercator
    return lng / (2 * math.pi) + 0.5, (1 - math.log(math.tan(lat) + (1 / math.cos(lat))) / math.pi) / 2
ValueError: math domain error
```

I have tried changing all the values (coordinates, image W H, zoom)
nothing worked, allthough sometimes when changing coordinates it randomly works (no idea why).

I have tried other stuf but its not worth descripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```py
s2sphere.LatLng(54.163849, -4.487915)
```

with

```py
staticmaps.create_latlng(54.163849, -4.487915)
# or
s2sphere.LatLng.from_degrees(54.163849, -4.487915)
```

[credits to a guy on github](https://github.com/flopp/py-staticmaps/issues/28#issuecomment-1339280250)